# How to update Dell customized VMWare ESXi 5.5 hosts

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell-poweredge

We've got two Dell R720 hosts running the Dell customized version of ESXi 5.5 they were installed with in 2014. I'd like to get these up to the [latest patch level](http://www.dell.com/support/home/ca/en/cabsdt1/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=D2NRN) but am unsure how to do so. We are strictly a Linux environment, so are not able to run VMWare Update Manager. I've found some instructions for doing this update using `esxcli` that look something like this:

```
esxcli software profile update -d https://hostupdate.vmware.com/software/VUM/PRODUCTION/main/vmw-depot-index.xml -p ESXi-5.5.0-20161204001-standard
```

But if I understand correctly this will take me to a "vanilla" install without Dell's custom features.

I like to think I'm a pretty competent Linux system and network admin, but I have little experience managing ESXi — these servers were set up and installed by outside consultants — and there's a lot of jargon around this process. So, hoping someone who's done this before can provide a step-by-step list. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem years ago and the only way was to get in touch with Dell Support to receive their customized build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some months later and I've done this update. The command above does the update without touching the Dell custom files. Here's what I ended up running:

```
esxcli system maintenanceMode set -e true
esxcli system maintenanceMode get
esxcli system version get
esxcli software profile update -d https://hostupdate.vmware.com/software/VUM/PRODUCTION/main/vmw-depot-index.xml -p ESXi-5.5.0-20170304001-standard
esxcli system shutdown reboot -r post-upgrade

esxcli system version get
esxcli system maintenanceMode set -e false
```

Running `esxcli software vib list` still shows a bunch of Dell, Broadcom, etc. entries from 2014, but many of the VMWare items have been updated. According to a [random blog comment](https://www.v-front.de/2013/09/how-to-update-your-standalone-host-to.html?showComment=1403030056662#c3822597472161650044), Dell does not provide updates in a form that can be used by `esxcli` and have to be done with VUM.